# Vlookup for text

Tags: excel

I am trying to use *vlookup* function. I am searching for string "C1212" in the cell with following text:

> C13,C20,C32,C34,C38,C48,C49,C50,C51,C52,C53,C57,C58,C62,C63,C64,C65,C66,C67,C68,C69,C70,C72,C73,C76,C78,C81,C82,C83,C85,C86,C90,C96,C101,C102,C110,C115,C116,C117,C122,C123,C138,C139,C142,C143,C147,C148,C153,C161,C162,C163,C164,C167,C168,C173,C174,C175,C176,C195,C196,C197,C204,C205,C217,C227,C229,C230,C231,C232,C233,C235,C236,C237,C241,C249,C250,C251,C252,C253,C254,C255,C256,C275,C276,C291,C292,C296,C306,C307,C313,C314,C320,C322,C323,C324,C326,C330,C332,C333,C334,C335,C337,C341,C345,C346,C347,C351,C352,C353,C354,C355,C356,C357,C358,C359,C360,C361,C362,C363,C364,C365,C366,C377,C379,C380,C381,C382,C383,C384,C385,C386,C387,C391,C392,C393,C394,C395,C396,C397,C398,C399,C400,C401,C402,C406,C407,C408,C409,C410,C411,C412,C415,C416,C417,C419,C420,C421,C422,C423,C424,C425,C428,C430,C431,C432,C433,C434,C435,C436,C437,C440,C441,C445,C446,C447,C448,C449,C450,C451,C453,C454,C455,C456,C457,C458,C459,C460,C461,C462,C463,C464,C465,C466,C477,C478,C479,C482,C485,C486,C487,C488,C490,C491,C492,C493,C494,C495,C496,C497,C501,C502,C503,C506,C507,C508,C509,C512,C513,C517,C518,C520,C521,C527,C530,C531,C534,C535,C541,C542,C543,C544,C545,C547,C552,C553,C554,C559,C560,C561,C565,C566,C568,C589,C596,C599,C600,C601,C604,C605,C610,C612,C613,C616,C617,C618,C619,C620,C621,C622,C624,C630,C631,C632,C633,C636,C637,C640,C641,C646,C647,C654,C655,C657,C658,C659,C661,C662,C663,C664,C665,C666,C667,C668,C669,C670,C671,C673,C674,C676,C677,C678,C679,C687,C689,C695,C697,C698,C699,C700,C701,C702,C703,C704,C705,C713,C714,C715,C716,C717,C718,C719,C720,C723,C735,C751,C753,C754,C755,C756,C757,C758,C759,C760,C766,C767,C776,C777,C783,C784,C787,C788,C789,C790,C795,C796,C800,C801,C802,C804,C805,C806,C807,C815,C816,C819,C821,C822,C825,C826,C829,C830,C832,C834,C836,C837,C838,C839,C841,C842,C844,C845,C846,C850,C852,C854,C858,C859,C860,C862,C864,C868,C869,C871,C873,C875,C876,C878,C880,C881,C885,C886,C890,C892,C893,C894,C895,C897,C899,C901,C902,C905,C906,C907,C908,C909,C910,C911,C912,C913,C914,C915,C916,C917,C918,C919,C920,C921,C922,C927,C928,C929,C931,C932,C933,C934,C940,C947,C949,C950,C953,C954,C955,C958,C962,C965,C972,C974,C977,C978,C980,C1010,C1017,C1019,C1022,C1025,C1026,C1027,C1030,C1035,C1036,C1043,C1044,C1045,C1046,C1047,C1048,C1050,C1052,C1058,C1061,C1065,C1067,C1068,C1071,C1072,C1074,C1075,C1078,C1081,C1083,C1084,C1086,C1087,C1089,C1090,C1091,C1093,C1094,C1096,C1097,C1098,C1099,C1103,C1104,C1105,C1109,C1110,C1111,C1114,C1115,C1116,C1120,C1121,C1122,C1123,C1124,C1125,C1126,C1127,C1130,C1133,C1135,C1138,C1139,C1141,C1146,C1150,C1151,C1154,C1155,C1162,C1168,C1169,C1170,C1178,C1179,C1183,C1184,C1188,C1189,C1190,C1191,C1192,C1194,C1198,C1199,C1200,C1201,C1202,C1203,C1204,C1205,C1206,C1207,C1208,C1209,C1210,C1211,C1212,C1213,C1214,C1216,C1223,C1224,C1225,C1226,C1241,C1242,C1270,C1271,C1272,C1273,C1283,C1288,C1289,C1290,C1291,C1292,C1293,C1297,C1298,C1305,C1306,C1310,C1311,C1312,C1320,C1321,C1336,C1337,C1338,C1340,C1341,C1342,C1346,C1349,C1360,C1365,C1366,C1368,C1372,C1373,C1374,C1378,C1381,C1382,C1383,C1388,C1389,C1390,C1396,C1401,C1412,C1413,C1414,C1415,C1416,C1417,C1418,C1419,C1423,C1427,C1428,C1429,C1433,C1439,C1450,C1451,C1457,C1458,C1463,C1464,C1465,C1470,C1472,C1473,C1474,C1475,C1476,C1477,C1478,C1479,C1480,C1481,C1482,C1484,C1486,C1487,C1488,C1489,C1490,C1491,C1492,C1493,C1494,C1496,C1498,C1499,C1501,C1502,C1513,C1519,C1521,C1522,C1525,C1528,C1532,C1536,C1537,C1542,C1543,C1544,C1546,C1548,C1550,C1551,C1554,C1555,C1556,C1557,C1558,C1559,C1560,C1561,C1562,C1565,C1567,C1568,C1569,C1571,C1576,C1577,C1578,C1579,C1580,C1589,C1591,C1592,C1593,C1596,C1597,C1598,C1599,C1600,C1602,C1607,C1608,C1617,C1618,C1619,C1622,C1623,C1625,C1626,C1627,C1628,C1629,C1630,C1632,C1633,C1634,C1638,C1639,C1640,C1643,C1647,C1649,C1655,C1656,C1657,C1660,C1661,C1662,C1664,C1665,C1666,C1667,C1668,C1669,C1670,C1671,C1674,C1675,C1676,C1677,C1678,C1679,C1683,C1688,C1689,C1690,C1691,C1693,C1694,C1704,C1711,C1712,C1717,C1718,C1725,C1727,C1728,C1729,C1730,C1731,C1739,C1740,C1741,C1742,C1743,C1755,C1756,C1763,C1764,C1768,C1769,C1786,C1788,C1789,C1794,C1795,C1796,C1804,C1816,C1828,C1850,C1851,C1852,C1854,C1855,C1857,C1858,C1859,C1860,C1867,C1868,C1872,C1880,C1886,C1889,C1890,C1897,C1903,C1905,C1910,C1913,C1914,C1915,C1917,C1929,C1930,C1935,C1937,C1938,C1939,C1942,C1943,C1944,C1945,C1946,C1948,C1949,C1950,C1951,C1953,C1954,C1955,C1956,C1958,C1959,C1960,C1963,C1964,C1965,C1967,C1969,C1970,C1971,C1972,C1973,C1975,C1978,C1979,C1983,C1984,C1985,C1986,C1987,C1988,C1989,C1990,C1991,C1992,C1993,C1994,C1995,C1996,C1997,C2009,C2014,C2016,C2020,C2021,C2022,C2023,C2024,C2025,C2029,C2030,C2032,C2033,C2035,C2036,C2039,C2040,C2041,C2042,C2049,C2050,C2051,C2057,C2059,C2060,C2075,C2082,C2083,C2087,C2090,C2091,C2093,C2094,C2108,C2111,C2112,C2114,C2115,C2124,C2125,C2126,C2131,C2132,C2133,C2136,C2137,C2141,C2142,C2158,C2159,C2161,C2181,C2201,C2210,C2217,C2218,C2300,C2301,C2306,C2349,C2354,C2355,C2386,C2392,C2400,C2406,C2415,C2416,C2417,C2422,C2483,C2484,C2493,C2544,C2545,C2546,C2547,C2572,C2611,C2612,C2613,C2614,C2629,C2631,C2632,C2668,C2669,C2670,C2671,C2672,C2673,C2674,C2675,C2680,C2681,C2682,C2694,C2721,C2722,C2738,C2739,C2749,C2762,C2787,C2801,C2816,C2852,C2853,C2942,C2943,C2944,C2948,C3044,C3045,C3052,C3053,C3061,C3062,C3068,C3074,C3077,C3078,C3079,C3085,C3086,C3087,C3092,C3093,C3094,C3095,C3099,C3100,C3102,C3108,C3109,C3110,C3111,C3120,C3123,C3133,C3134,C3146,C3148,C3149,C3153,C3154,C3156,C3163,C3164,C3185,C3197,C3203,C3219,C3220,C3221,C3222,C3224,C3247,C3248,C3249,C3255,C3256,C3257,C3258,C3269,C3270,C3288,C3289,C3290,C3291,C3292,C3293,C3301,C3302,C3303,C3304,C3305,C3306,C3310,C3312,C3313,C3314,C3324,C3329,C3330,C3338,C3339,C3340,C3341,C3343,C3344,C3345,C3346,C3347,C3354,C3355,C3356,C3360,C3362,C3371,C3375,C3379,C3385,C3393,C3438,C3442,C3453,C3469,C3470,C3471,C3474,C3476,C3487,C3494,C3509,C3515,C3525,C3542,C3543,C3549,C3557,C3564,C3568,C3569,C3570,C3571,C3580,C3582,C3594,C3599,C3601,C3603,C3604,C3605,C3608,C3609,C3637,C3638,C3639,C3640,C3644,C3645,C3656,C3663,C3664,C3676,C3692,C3697,C3708,C3709,C3713,C3714,C3724,C3737,C3738,C3760,C3761,C3762,C3774,C3776,C3789,C3796,C3813,C3815,C3831,C3844,C3850,C3855,C3856,C3861,C3882,C3883,C3884,C3885,C3888,C3901,C3905,C3906,C3915,C3942,C3960,C3961,C3962,C3963,C3964,C3965,C3966,C3982,C3983,C3984,C3985,C3992,C3993,C4012,C4025,C4039,C4041,C4046,C4051,C4064,C9002,C9003,C9004,C9005,C9010,C9011,C9012,C9013,C9014,C9015,C9016,C9017,C9018,C9019,C9020,C9021,C9022,C9023,C9024,C9025,C9026,C9027,C9028,C9029,C9030,C9031,C9032,C9033,C9034,C9035,C9036,C9037,C9038,C9039,C9040,C9041,C9042,C9043,C9044,C9045,C9046,C9047,C9048,C9049,C9050,C9051,C9052,C9053,C9054,C9055,C9056,C9057,C9058,C9059,C9060,C9061,C9062,C9063,C9064,C9065,C9066,C9067,C9068,C9069,C9070,C9071,C9072,C9073,C9074,C9075,C9076,C9077,C9078,C9079,C9080,C9081,C9082,C9083,C9084,C9085,C9086,C9087,C9088,C9089

And then I would want to put the next column's value in my table. But excel is always returning N/A..
This is the formula I used:

```
VLOOKUP("*"&"C1212"&"*",G3,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use Vlookup? What do you expect the result to be? Vlookup is for looking up a value in a table, and returning another.  What do you want to do when you find C1212?

Comment: When vlookup finds C1212 in a particular row of the column, I want it to return to the value of next column of the same row. I gave only one cell as example here. This formula is working ok for cells with three/four values but with so many values like in this example. It's returning error.

Comment: And all that text in in *one* cell?  Say that's in A1, then you have another cell, A2, that has other numbers, such as `D13,D20,D32,D34,...`?

Comment: yes, that text is one cell, say A1. The other cells are in same column A2, A3... and so on till A470.

Comment: For one thing, your `vlookup` is wrong. The second parameter needs to be a range, not just a cell. If you are looking up into Column A and wanting to return the corresponding data in Column B, then, theoretically, it would be `=VLOOKUP("*"&"C1212"&"*",A1:B470,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Furthermore, because "C1212" is a string, then you don't need to concatenate here, so `=VLOOKUP("*C1212*",A1:B470,2,FALSE)`. This doesn't fix the problem you are running into, but it removes a few headscratchers for folks that might know what's wrong here.

Comment: Yes it's a range. I just put a cell here to illustrate that I am facing issue with particular cell

Comment: Looks like Excel has a 255 character limit on wildcard searches like this. There are some workarounds, but they are not pretty: http://eforexcel.com/wp/overcome-wildcard-vlookup-match-problem-when-target-string-is-more-than-255-characters/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try if it solves my problem.

Comment: I tried the method in the link. But the search is returning wrongly matched results, suppose if I am searching the corresponding value for C121 and the cell containing C1212 is found first, the lookup puts its corresponding value instead of C121's.